# I want to dump data which is received by MQTT broker to the sqlite3 db provided by Django/

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mqtt

I am using a mqtt broker in my code and it is reading some data for particular user.How can i dump this data for that user for activity log in sqlite3 db ,which is provided by Django.

Answer (score 1):

Different approaches for doing this are described here: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/

To sum up, you have essentially two possibilities

- Using a wildcard subscriber application which stores the data to the DB
- Intercept messages directly at the broker and then persist it to the DB

Comment: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/ I dont know how to use this ..Actually i have started mqtt broker on one terminal .. but dont know how to pass the data to the sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Node-RED (http://nodered.org) with a MQTT subscriber node and a sqlite output node.